# Custom Edge with jgrapht

Tags: java, jgrapht

I want to define a custom edge

```
public class Connection extends DefaultWeightedEdge
```

But when I try to use the `super()`is that possible? What should I use for EdgeFactory when creating a graph?

```
new SimpleWeightedGraph<Sensor, Connection>(EdgeFactory.class);
```

Would this be sufficient? Or should I create a new class who extends `EdgeFactory` as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not require to subclass `DefaultWeightedEdge` to create your custom edge, the following works also. I'm currently using version 0.9.0 of JGraphT.

Class definition :

```
public class Connection {
    // class implementation
    // define all constructors and methods you need
}
```

Graph creation :

```
SimpleWeightedGraph<Sensor, Connection> graph;
graph = new SimpleWeightedGraph<Sensor, Connection>(Connection.class);
```

Adding custom edge and setting weight :

```
Sensor v1 = // sensor instance
Sensor v2 = // another sensor instance
graph.addVertex(v1);
graph.addVertex(v2);

Connection connection = new Connection(/* ... */);
graph.addEdge(v1, v2, connection);
graph.setEdgeWeight(connection, 10.0);
```

Also consider to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your `Connection` class, as JGraphT relies on those methods since version 0.8.4, see [EqualsAndHashCode](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/Users%3A-EqualsAndHashCode) article. This article also provides an example where `DefaultWeightedEdge` is subclassed.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you in creating custom edges ?

This particular example is drawn from the JGrapht internal documentation . Search for StoerWagnerMinimumCut algorithm inside the code base .

Here we go .

The idea here is to give some weights to the edges of the graph hence the need to manipulate the default weights.

```
final WeightedGraph<Set<V>, DefaultWeightedEdge> workingGraph;
....

workingGraph =
            new SimpleWeightedGraph<Set<V>, DefaultWeightedEdge>(
                DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
list = ....
workingGraph.addVertex(list);
....
```

// Lets manipulate the edge weights now

```
DefaultWeightedEdge eNew = workingGraph.getEdge(someSourcEdge, someTargetEdge);
        if (eNew == null) {
            eNew = workingGraph.addEdge(someSourcEdge, someTargetEdge);
            workingGraph.setEdgeWeight(eNew, graph.getEdgeWeight(e));
        } else {
            workingGraph.setEdgeWeight(
                eNew,
                workingGraph.getEdgeWeight(eNew) + graph.getEdgeWeight(e));
```

I hope you can play around with the example and use it to create customized edges .

`PS :` My answer my not be 100% correct but the idea is to point you to the correct direction in the docmentation :-)